# app still running after disable

Tags: android, service, bootcompleted

I’ve installed an app I’ve written as a system app that after receiving ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED it runs a service.

The app works just fine, however, I would like to disable it (and not remove it completely).

So I wrote on the command line “adb shell pm disable [The package name]” and after reboot, even though I do not see my app on the menu anymore, I still get a message “Unfortunately [myApp] has stopped”.

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service [package name] : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "[packagename.classThatStartsTheService]" on path: /system/app/app.apk 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2516) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5074) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "[packagename.class that starts the service]" on path: /system/app/app.apk  
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2513) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1356):    ... 10 more
```

Does that mean the boot_completed is still recognized by my app but because it is disabled it cannot run? Or is it something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently I had another app that had the option to activate my app (only when choosing so and not by default), so after reboot, it couldn’t find it’s apk as it was disabled. So I disabled the second app as well.

Comment: how did the other app start the disabled one, if it's disabled? can disabled apps be opened?

Comment: That’s the point. It couldn’t start it because it was disabled, however it tried anyways and then the pop-up message appeared.

You can re-enable an application by “adb shell pm enable [package name]” on cmd.

Comment: ohhhh.... sorry . I missed this part. tell me this: would choosing "force stop" as an end user (via the "manage apps" screen) force the app to stay in "stopped" mode, so that the app's broadcast receivers won't get any intents till the app is started? that's how installation of new apps work, so I wonder if that's the same for this operation too.

Comment: As far as I know, it just stops the current process but doesn’t stay in that mode so broadcast messages can still be received...